# XAMPP chiper suite

Tags: apache, xampp

Trying to enable elliptic curves on the latest XAMPP on Windows, via.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384
 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH
 EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Adding this to my SSL-enabled vhost makes apache unable to start. Is there anything I need to enable in addition, in the apache config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently XAMPP does not like line breaks. Making the SSLCipherSuite be all on one line solved the problem.